# By considering a right-angled triangle, Prove that if $A$ is an acute angle, then $\tan(90-A)=\frac1{\tan A }$.

Tags: trigonometry

By considering a right-angled triangle, Prove that if $A$ is an acute angle, then $\tan(90-A)=\dfrac1{\tan A}$.

I'm not too sure with this question, would it be a good starting point by  using the identity $\tan x=\dfrac{\sin x}{\cos x}$ ?

Comment: Have you draw a triangle?

Comment: $A+B=90^{0}$ consider $ \cot(A+B)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\tan(90-A) = \sin(90°-A)/\cos(90°-A) = \cos(A) / \sin(A) = 1/\tan(A)$

Answer (score 1):

If the legs are
$a$ and $b$
opposite corresponding angles
$A$ and $B$ then
$\tan(A) = a/b$
and
$\tan(B) = b/a$.

But $A+B = 90$
so
$\tan(B)
=\tan(90-A)
=b/a
=1/(a/b)
=1/\tan(A)
$.